# CMake File Error

Tags: cmake, kaa

I have been trying to complete and compile the sdk code on the raspberry pi 3 model that I have, but have been unsuccessful at figuring out the error that is below.

Please let me know if anyone has had this error before and if you have some way to solve it.

> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler:
>   /home/pi/rpi_root/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
>   Build flags:  Id flags:
>
> The output was: 2
>   /home/pi/rpi_root/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   1:
>   /home/pi/rpi_root/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   Syntax error: "(" unexpected
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler:
>   /home/pi/rpi_root/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
>   Build flags:  Id flags: -c
>
> The output was: 2
>   /home/pi/rpi_root/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   1:
>   /home/pi/rpi_root/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   Syntax error: "(" unexpected
>
> Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR
>   .+ Compiler":
>   /home/pi/rpi_root/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   1:
>   /home/pi/rpi_root/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   Syntax error: "(" unexpected Determining if the CXX compiler works
>   failed with the following output: Change Dir:
>   /home/pi/rpi_root/Botan-1.11.27/kaa-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_1a2a7/fast" /usr/bin/make -f
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_1a2a7.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_1a2a7.dir/build
>   make[1]: Entering directory
>   '/home/pi/rpi_root/Botan-1.11.27/kaa-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_1a2a7.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
>   /home/pi/rpi_root/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
>   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_1a2a7.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /home/pi/rpi_root/Botan-1.11.27/kaa-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
>   /home/pi/rpi_root/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   1:
>   /home/pi/rpi_root/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   Syntax error: "(" unexpected CMakeFiles/cmTC_1a2a7.dir/build.make:65:
>   recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_1a2a7.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o'
>   failed make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_1a2a7.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o]
>   Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory
>   '/home/pi/rpi_root/Botan-1.11.27/kaa-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_1a2a7/fast' failed make: ***
>   [cmTC_1a2a7/fast] Error 2
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
>   Build flags:  Id flags:
>
> The output was: 2
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   1:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   Syntax error: "(" unexpected
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
>   Build flags:  Id flags: -c
>
> The output was: 2
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   1:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   Syntax error: "(" unexpected
>
> Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR
>   .+ Compiler":
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   1:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   Syntax error: "(" unexpected Determining if the CXX compiler works
>   failed with the following output: Change Dir:
>   /home/pi/rpi_root/Botan-1.11.27/kaa-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_39dde/fast" /usr/bin/make -f
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_39dde.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_39dde.dir/build
>   make[1]: Entering directory
>   '/home/pi/rpi_root/Botan-1.11.27/kaa-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_39dde.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
>   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_39dde.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /home/pi/rpi_root/Botan-1.11.27/kaa-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   1:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   Syntax error: "(" unexpected CMakeFiles/cmTC_39dde.dir/build.make:65:
>   recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_39dde.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o'
>   failed make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_39dde.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o]
>   Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory
>   '/home/pi/rpi_root/Botan-1.11.27/kaa-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_39dde/fast' failed make: ***
>   [cmTC_39dde/fast] Error 2
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
>   Build flags:  Id flags:
>
> The output was: 2
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   1:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   Syntax error: "(" unexpected
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
>   Build flags:  Id flags: -c
>
> The output was: 2
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   1:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   Syntax error: "(" unexpected
>
> Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR
>   .+ Compiler":
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   1:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   Syntax error: "(" unexpected Determining if the CXX compiler works
>   failed with the following output: Change Dir:
>   /home/pi/rpi_root/Botan-1.11.27/kaa-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_2bd57/fast" /usr/bin/make -f
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_2bd57.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_2bd57.dir/build
>   make[1]: Entering directory
>   '/home/pi/rpi_root/Botan-1.11.27/kaa-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_2bd57.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
>   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_2bd57.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /home/pi/rpi_root/Botan-1.11.27/kaa-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   1:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   Syntax error: "(" unexpected CMakeFiles/cmTC_2bd57.dir/build.make:65:
>   recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_2bd57.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o'
>   failed make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_2bd57.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o]
>   Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory
>   '/home/pi/rpi_root/Botan-1.11.27/kaa-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_2bd57/fast' failed make: ***
>   [cmTC_2bd57/fast] Error 2
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
>   Build flags:  Id flags:
>
> The output was: 2
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   1:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   Syntax error: "(" unexpected
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
>   Build flags:  Id flags: -c
>
> The output was: 2
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   1:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   Syntax error: "(" unexpected
>
> Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR
>   .+ Compiler":
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   1:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   Syntax error: "(" unexpected Determining if the CXX compiler works
>   failed with the following output: Change Dir:
>   /home/pi/rpi_root/Botan-1.11.27/kaa-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_8d1c9/fast" /usr/bin/make -f
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_8d1c9.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_8d1c9.dir/build
>   make[1]: Entering directory
>   '/home/pi/rpi_root/Botan-1.11.27/kaa-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_8d1c9.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
>   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_8d1c9.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /home/pi/rpi_root/Botan-1.11.27/kaa-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   1:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   Syntax error: "(" unexpected CMakeFiles/cmTC_8d1c9.dir/build.make:65:
>   recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_8d1c9.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o'
>   failed make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_8d1c9.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o]
>   Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory
>   '/home/pi/rpi_root/Botan-1.11.27/kaa-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_8d1c9/fast' failed make: ***
>   [cmTC_8d1c9/fast] Error 2
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
>   Build flags:  Id flags:
>
> The output was: 2
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   1:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   Syntax error: "(" unexpected
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
>   Build flags:  Id flags: -c
>
> The output was: 2
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   1:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   Syntax error: "(" unexpected
>
> Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR
>   .+ Compiler":
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   1:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   Syntax error: "(" unexpected Determining if the CXX compiler works
>   failed with the following output: Change Dir:
>   /home/pi/rpi_root/Botan-1.11.27/kaa-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_904a4/fast" /usr/bin/make -f
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_904a4.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_904a4.dir/build
>   make[1]: Entering directory
>   '/home/pi/rpi_root/Botan-1.11.27/kaa-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_904a4.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
>   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_904a4.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /home/pi/rpi_root/Botan-1.11.27/kaa-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   1:
>   /home/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++:
>   Syntax error: "(" unexpected CMakeFiles/cmTC_904a4.dir/build.make:65:
>   recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_904a4.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o'
>   failed make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_904a4.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o]
>   Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory
>   '/home/pi/rpi_root/Botan-1.11.27/kaa-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_904a4/fast' failed make: ***
>   [cmTC_904a4/fast] Error 2

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem when using C SDK. I tried to use the default gcc in Raspberry as compiler, and everything works fine. Maybe you can also try to compile the C++ SDK based on the C++ Linux guide but C++ Raspberry pi guide.